# Nautilus - How to open a bookmark folder with keyboard in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys

The way it worked in 16.04:

- open nautilus
- switch back and forth between the left pane ('places'?) and the folder view with <kbd>F6</kbd>
- when you are in the left pane and a bookmarked folder is highlighted you can press <kbd>enter</kbd> to open it

Now in 18.04:

- if you have just opened nautilus you can go down with the arrow keys in the left pane and press enter to open a bookmarked folder
- Then when you have gone to the right side with <kbd>F6</kbd> or simply after opening the first folder with files
- You can switch back to the left side with <kbd>F6</kbd> and select a different bookmarked folder with your arrow keys
- but pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> now opens the file that is in focus on the right, instead of opening the folder on the left pane that is in focus

So, how do I open a bookmarked folder in nautilus with my keyboard? (after already opened one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the highlighted location.

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would open the highlighted location in a new window and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would open the highlighted location in a new tab.

Comment: It may not work when you have a **folder** in focus on the right, but should work alright if you have a **file** focussed on the right.

Comment: Ah yes that works! (even with a folder in focus on the right). Do you happen to know if there is some way to get the old behaviour back?

Comment: @Sebastian No idea, sorry :( Consider reporting a bug to the developers.